# find all self-complementary graphs on five vertices

Tags: graph-theory

I know that the two complements should have an equal number of edges, namely $\binom{5}{2}/2=5$.
Since there are 10 possible edges, there are at least $\binom{10}{5}/2=126$ possible pairs of graph-complement pairs.

But after making drawings for the same problem with four vertices, I know many of them are isomorphic and can be obtained from by rotations and reflections.

How should I proceed in eliminating these isomorphic graphs?

In the first place, am I taking the right approach, or is their a more effective solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sum of degrees is $10$, and since the graph is self complementary, by symmetry the degree sequence must be

$$(d_1,d_2, 2,4-d_2,4-d_1) \,,$$

where $d_1, d_2 \in \{ 0,1,2 \}$, and $d_1 \leq d_2$.

It is easy to see that $d_1=0$ is not possible, since then the last degree would be $4$, thus $d_1, d_2 \in \{ 1,2 \}$, and $d_1 \leq d_2$.

**Case $1$** $d_1=1, d_2=1$. Your degree sequence is $(1,1,2,3,3)$. Each of the vertices of degree $3$ must be connected to all vertices excluding one end vertex. There is only one graph up to isomorphism.

**Case $2$** $d_1=1, d_2=2$. Your degree sequence is $(1,2,2,2,3)$. You have two graphs here: the end vertex is connected to a degree $2$ or $3$.

**Case $3$** $d_1=2, d_2=2$. Your graph is connected (why?) and has all degrees $2$. Only 1 possibility.

Comment: >Your graph is connected (why?)
Because the graph reduces to (2,2,2,2,2) -> (1,1,2,2,2) -> (1,1,1,1).
Hence, (2,2,2,2,2) is a graphical sequence.
Or more simply, the graph is C5.
Was this your intended answer?

Comment: My intention was connected implies $C_5$. Why is your graph $C_5$ then? ;)

Comment: Actually I can't explain why; can you help me?
I began with assuming G was not $C_5$ and had degree sequence (2,2,2,2,2). I want to say G is not connected, but I don't know how.

Comment: @user81055 Assume by contradiction that $G$ is disconnected. Then one component must have at most two vertices. But then the vertices cannot have degree 2.

Answer (score 3):

Non-isomorphic 5-edge 5-vertex graph representatives are drawn below with their non-edges in orange (generated using `geng 5 5:5`, which comes with Nauty):

[image]

We include the degree sequences below the graphs.

We can eyeball these to see which are self-complementary: the bottom-left and bottom-right.

Of the four possibilities given in [N.S.'s answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/411956/91818), only two are self-complementary, which we can redraw:

[image]

Comment: It's totally unclear to me what's the systematic behind it although the answer is correct.

Comment: It's a computational solution; it can e.g. be used to verify the correctness of mathematical solutions (and knowing the answer can aid in coming up with a mathematical solution).  I guess `geng` uses a canonical construction path method for generating non-isomorphic graphs; I'm not too sure.